# Unable to Reset the Arduino Leonardo Code

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I was trying to learn about the keyboard simulation using Arduino Leonardo Pro Mini.

The code i wrote was

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
Keyboard.begin()
}

void loop() {
Keyboard.println("Hello World");
}
```

This works fine, now i want to reset the microcontroller with the empty code, which is

```cpp
void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

But the previous code doesn't let me do this.
The following is the error, even though the port selection is correct (i am sure about that)

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not related to the code you're uploading.

Caused by:

- missing bootloader
- broken bootloader
- wrong bootloader settings
- faulty connection
- stuff connected to hardware Rx/Tx ...

Comment: So is there any way to get rid of it and burn new and fresh code?

Comment: On your request, I have found that its not burning because of busy Rx/Tx